# Twitter API- rate update limits

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, limits

I keep having this issue when working with the Twitter API

```
Exception in thread "main" 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Missing or invalid url parameter.
code - 195

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:

    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=506c3b98 or

    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1136695b
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[506c3b98-1136695b], statusCode=403, message=Missing or invalid url parameter., code=195, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=177, limit=180, resetTimeInSeconds=1467915200, secondsUntilReset=691}, version=4.0.4}
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1786)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:255)
at TwitterAPI.TwitterDataRetrieve.getTweetsByHashTag(TwitterDataRetrieve.java:98)
at test.Twittertest.main(Twittertest.java:37)
```

I googled it and it seems like its about the rate limits, how can i solve it?

Comment: Can you please show us the code you are using. Very hard to work out the solution without that.

Comment: Please format your post.